# Как из датафрейма Pandas поудалять почти дубликаты строк?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Прошу у сообщества совета вот пот такой задачке:
Есть датафрейм (`['Операция', 'Время_операции', 'Пользователь', 'Имя_модели', 'Контекст', Комментарий', 'Оставшееся_время_расчёта', 'Тип_рассчета', 'Узел', 'Этап']`), созданный из лога. В логе есть информация как о корректных запусках/завершениях расчетов (тогда в колоноке 'Этап' после статуса "Запуск" через n-ое количество строк идет статус "Успешно завершено"). Но есть и записи о холостых запусках, в этом случае идет статус "Запуск", а потом, через n-ое количество строк с другими статусами снова повторяется статус "Запуск". 
Мне надо почистить датафрейм от строк с упоминанием холостых запусков, чтобы число запусков соответствовало числу завершений. 
Пытался просто удалять дубликаты делать через  subset с параметром keep='last'

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Пользователь','Контекст','Комментарий','Тип_рассчета','Узел','Этап'], keep='last')
```

, но не получается, т.к. часто строки отличаются только временем. Если добавить фильтр еще и дату, то тоже не получется, т.к. холостой и корректный запуски могут в разные даты быть. В общем, корректно удалить дубликаты не получается :(
Сейчас вижу только вариант построчного перебора датафрейма. Но т.к. я только учусь еще и в питоне и пандасе пока руку не набил, то не могу сообразить, как все это реализовать в коде. Пусть хотя бы выловить все правильные запуски и завершения в новый df.

По шагам мыслю так:

1. Делаем пустой df с колонками, как в исходном df.
2. Ищем в исходном df первую строку со статусом "Запуск", добавляем ее в новый 
    df.
3. Смотрим следующую строку в исходном df, если статус не "Запуск" и не
   "Завершение" - пропускаем, если статус снова "Запуск" - то надо из
   нового df удалить предудыщую строку со статусом "Запуск" и записать
   вновь найденную, если статус "Завершение" - то добавляем в новый df.

Как-то не могу в голове это все в коде увязать. И может не в самом пандасе это все крутить надо, а df в словарь преобразовать и уже там возиться?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

Исходные:

```
import pandas as pd

# df для примера
log = {'Status':['Запуск', 'Запуск', 'Успешно завершено',
           'Запуск', 'Запуск', 'Успешно завершено',
           'Запуск', 'Успешно завершено', 'Запуск',
           'Успешно завершено'],
           'Code':[313, 123, 333, 222, 111,
            4343, 444, 555, 2332, 1]}
df  = pd.DataFrame(log)
```

Будет такой df:

```
              Status  Code
0             Запуск   313
1             Запуск   123
2  Успешно завершено   333
3             Запуск   222
4             Запуск   111
5  Успешно завершено  4343
6             Запуск   444
7  Успешно завершено   555
8             Запуск  2332
9  Успешно завершено     1
```

Делаем группировку и выдергиваем первую группу:

```
groups = df.groupby((df['Status'] != df['Status'].shift()))
res = [group for key, group in groups if key][0]
print(res)
```

Получаем:

```
             Status  Code
0             Запуск   313
2  Успешно завершено   333
3             Запуск   222
5  Успешно завершено  4343
6             Запуск   444
7  Успешно завершено   555
8             Запуск  2332
9  Успешно завершено     1
```

Comment: Добрый день! Большое спасибо за ответ. Мне уже дали подсказку, как сделать через cumsum, помогло. Но ваш вариант кажется проще. Обязательно проанализирую ваш способ, т.к. задача получила развитие и надо будет копаться дальше. А разносторонний опыт - всегда полезен.